# Terraform: Automatically populate module's variables

Tags: terraform

I am calling a `terraform` module from my `main.tf` as follows:

```
module "vpc" {
  source                  = "./modules/vpc"
  match_pub_ip_env_vpc_sn = true
  env_vpc_sg_name         = "My name"
  env_vpc_sg_desc         = "My description"
}
```

My question is this: Can I use a file to populate the call to the above module with the values I want for the above variables without explicitly adding them in the `module` statement (as above). If so is there a file naming convention that `terraform` uses for such a purpose? (i.e. without me needing to pass `-vars-file` in the cmd?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. It's like a method/function call. The module needs to declare what variables it takes (eg the signature or parameter list in a programming language, with some being defaulted if not set) and then the caller of the module needs to pass any required variables when it declares the module.

Comment: I guess that is the problem that `terragrunt` is trying to solve, right?